# Find control where javascript is running

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, user-controls, ascx

I have a user control named `uscUserControl.ascx` and a page named `test.aspx`.
I have used user control twice on my page. My user control looks like.

```
<div id="div1">
</div>
<script>
   $(document).ready() (function() {$('[id$=div1]').html('Control called');}  );
</script>
```

But it only modifies first div and second is empty. So how to make script modify the element nearest to it?

Comment: use a combination of closest/parent/siblings

Comment: in your javascript of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can solve it using combination of `ClientID` and partial Id as below

```
$(document).ready() (function() {$('[id*=<%= ClientID %>][id$=div1]').html('Control called');}  );
```